# Connect to dhcp printer server

Tags: dhcp

Hope someone can help me.

Knowing that on Windows, what I do is to open Windows explorer and tape \\srv-dhcp. How to do the equivalent on Ubuntu?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have the latest version of Ubuntu (Precise Pangolin) so here:

1. click on the Dash (the one with the Ubuntu logo) on the left
2. type 'Print' and select Printing
3. click 'Add'
4. then select Network Printer
5. enter the Print Server address to connect

I hope that helps

Comment: Thank you, but how to find the Print Server address?

Comment: Once you are in the New Printer window, choose Find Network Printer in the left pane under Network Printer. If you know the host name, which in this case I assume is srv-'dhcp', type it in the box then click 'Find' and select it from the results.

Answer (score 0):

Some printer have *Bonjour* protocol activated so you can see its implementation in Linux *Avahi*. So you can point to it as printername.local or use Avahi discover to get its IP.

See [Avahi (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avahi_%28software%29)